# Handling authentication in a Spring Boot REST API with a firebase token obtained from a front-end app

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, spring-boot-starter

I am new to Spring Boot and Firebase. I have generated REST endpoints from my model and repositories using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

I also created a front-end application (front is a SPA written in React - back works with Spring boot - these are 2 separate apps).
My front-end app contains a login form and I use the Firebase JS SDK to authenticate the user and get an ID token for him.

Now I would like to add authentication to my endpoints so only authorized users can reach them, using the token I get in the front-end app.

I can put the token in the `Authorization` header of each request, but I dont't know how to:

- Extract and check the token in Spring Boot, in order to get user information. [I saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807295/615882), is this ok?
- Pass the user information to the endpoint methods (currently I got no controller, since they are generated from the repositories (they extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` or `CrudRepository`))
- Specify which endpoints are public and which are private (using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I guess).
- Also, some endpoints could be accessible only by some users. But I saw nothing in Firebase that allows me to distinct user grants.

I have read several tutorials but I have not enough details to understand everything, and they do not answer all my questions.

Thanks